# Datatable doesn't load me Jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables, css-tables

I have a table with data from a database. I want to paginate the table, i search for a method and i found https://datatables.net . This looks like too simple... But this does not work in my project... I think that is because i have many CDN and i have a conflict with these CDN (i have 2 cdn of bootstrap, but i want 5.0 v)
My question: is for this reason?
code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleMenu.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleImagenProfile.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleMenuBtnPerfil.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylePaginado.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js"></script>
```

table:

```
<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%;" class="table table-striped table-dark">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Fecha de creacion</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Tiempo desarrollado</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Tipo de proyecto</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Estado</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Opciones</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <c:forEach var="proyecto" items="${lista}">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>${proyecto.nombre}</td>
                                            <td>${proyecto.fechaInicio}</td>
                                            <td>${proyecto.hsTrabajadas}</td>
                                            <td>${proyecto.tipoProyecto.tipoProyecto}</td>
                                            <td>${proyecto.estado.estado}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a class="btn btn-success" href="/AdministrarProyectos/DatosProyectoServlet?id=${proyecto.id}">Ir al proyecto</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </table>
```

CDN of the bottom:

```
<script src="js/paginador.js"></script> <!-- THE CODE FOR PAGINATE THE TABLE -->
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
} );
```

I try put the code into the top but it has no effect...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _"does not work"_? What happens? Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I think you are right - the resources are probably causing the problem. My suggestion is that you remove _all_ your current resources, and use the [download builder](https://datatables.net/download/index), to create a new set (and place them all in the page header, by the way). Do not change the order in which the resources are listed. Get this working first - even if it is not what you ultimately want. Then make changes to the resources, one change at a time, and test after each change. Update your question with the results if/when you hit a specific problem.

Comment: datatables is dependent on jQuery so order of loading is important

Comment: @andrewjames only show the table with 150 rows without the paginator

Comment: @charlietfl ty! I start a new simple project for try cleanly and it works